# Where are the layman non-prerequisite introductory materials for everything-testing in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

**This question has been modified**

If I had to really pick the kind of testing I would like to learn (I have no idea which way this translates to Python) is found here http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd. I don't know if this is agile, extreme or if it's just called TDD. Is this unit testing, doc testing a combination of both or am I missing something? Is there something even better, similar or is this style simply not applicable? I am looking for extreme beginners material on how to do testing (specifically for Python) as described in my link. I am open to ideas and all Python resources. Thanks!

I pasted the original message here for reference
http://dpaste.com/274603/plain/

Comment: What kind of Testing are we talking about here ? Is the underlying application written in python?

Comment: Wow.  A lot of words but no real information.  What do you know?  What are you trying to do?  A list of failure modes isn't helpful.  Please update this question with a **short** summary of what you are attempting to do and what code you have so far. Please focus on the thing you are trying to **do**. The long story is just confusing with too many words and too few facts.

Comment: @anijhaw honestly. I have no idea at this point. One sec

Comment: @anijhaw Python. Testing and Python in general is imho an extremely ad-hoc afterthought subject to learn from scratch. I have no idea if I should learn X to test before, during or after or use Y only during and Z before. What style of testing is best for my approach with which combination of the former? I have no idea what testing I need but believe what I am asking for is TDD in Python **but** wait. I don't really know if I need that. My question is where do I start figuring out testing as a whole then pick and choose the testing that I need then learn it as if it were speaking to a dummy...

Comment: @S.Lott sorry. My question isn't meant to boost rep or what ever you might call it here. It isn't also meant to suck the blood out of those who are willing to help. If you're TL:DR please read only the title and before you answer **assume** I was an extreme dummy. I have no testing history under my belt. How many different approaches to it? I have no frigging clue. What's best for me? I like turtles. Now insert my title here and I hope it gets to the point.

Comment: @user503568: "My question is where do I start figuring out testing as a whole".  Please rewrite the question to actually say that.  Please drop the sad background stories and focus on what you need to know.

Comment: @user503568: "please read only the title and before you answer assume I was an extreme dummy."  If only the title matters than cut the words down so that it's clear what the question is.  If you want specific help, please ask a specific question.  Focus, please.

Comment: @S.Lott I am asking for understanding of my situation. I think only if you could understand my frustration and confusion you'd be able to help. I really need to avoid just anybody coming here and posting just any link to any one particular testing technique and pitching it as the only way. What Python focused materials can cover all ground maybe quickly then delve deeper into them from scratch enabling me to being able to approach a particular testing style with some understanding that'll help me decipher its documentation? I just don't think my question is simple enough without background.

Comment: @user503568:  "I just don't think my question is simple enough without background".  Take the hint.  To get a useful answer, your question **must** be simple.  Omit the background.  This isn't our first rodeo.  We really can help you without the emotional baggage.  Your level and depth of frustration don't help us.  Your simple formulation, "My question is where do I start figuring out testing as a whole" seems to be all that's necessary.  Your emotional state isn't part of the question and won't be addressed in any answer.  Please remove it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to start with is Python's `unittest` module. There are frameworks to do things more automatically later on, but unittest works fine for simple cases.

The basic idea is that you have a class for a particular test suite. You define a set of test methods, and optional `setUp` and `tearDown` methods to be executed before and after each test in that suite. Within each test, you can use various assert* methods to check that things work.

Finally, you call unittest.main() to run all the tests you've defined.

Have a look at this example: http://docs.python.org/library/unittest#basic-example

Comment: And for what it's worth: I've been there too. I'm an amateur programmer, I found automated testing confusing when I first ran into it. If you want to write anything more than a dozen lines, though, it's worth getting your head around. A few good tests make it really easy to find when you break something.

Answer (score 1):

> What resources do you fellas have for starting out in testing in particular to Python? ... What are the most excellent places to start out at, anybody?

Step 1.  Write less.

Step 2.  Focus.

Step 3.  Identify in clear, simple sentences what you are testing.  Is it software?  What does it do?  What architecture does it run on?  Specifically list the specific things you're actually going to test.  Specific.  Focused.

Step 4.  For one thing you're going to test.  One thing.  Pick a requirement it must meet.  One requirement.  I.e., "Given x and y as input, computes z."

Looking at your question, I feel you might find this to be very, very hard.  But it's central to testing.  Indeed, this is all that testing is.

- You must have something to test.  (A
  "fixture".)
- You must have requirements against
  which to test it.  (A "TestCase".)
- You have have measurable pass/fail
  criteria.  (An "assertion".)

If you don't have that, you can't test.  It helps to write it down in words.  Short, focused lists of fixtures, cases and assertions.  Short.  Focused.

Once you've got one requirement, testing is just coding the requirements into a language that asserts the results of each test case.  Nothing more.

Your `unittest.TestCase` uses `setUp` to create a fixture.  A `TestCase` can have one or more test methods to exercise the fixture in different ways.  Each test method has one or more assertions about the fixture.

Once you have a test case which passes, you can move back to Step 4 and do one more requirement.

Once you have all the requirements for a fixture, you go back to Step 3 and do one more fixture.

Build up your tests slowly.  In pieces.  Write less.  Focus.

Comment: I love the 'write less, focus' bit. A little like Mark Twain's "Sorry for the length of this letter, I wanted to write a shorter one but didn't have time"

Answer (score 0):

I like [this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/24584/How-to-Think-Like-a-Computer-Scientist-Learning-with-Python-) one and [this](http://www.diveintopython.net/) one too

Comment: Thanks Kevin but I am not looking for introductory materials to Python but in particular to testing *in* Python. The question isn't asking for results to googles "python testing" either. I been there. Preferably some real world resources from persons whom were perhaps in my position and understand my frustration and have a link to resources that cover my real question is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I found the testing part of diveintopython to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Testing is more of an art, and you get better through practice.

For myself, I have read this **book** [Pragmatic Unit Testing in C# with NUnit](http://pragprog.com/titles/utc2/pragmatic-unit-testing-in-c-with-nunit), and I'll really recommend it to you. 
Although its about .Net and C# and not about Python, you can skip the exact code, but try to understand the principles being taught.

It contains good examples about what one should look out for when designing tests. And also, what kind of code should be written that supports the tests-first paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to C. Titus Brown's Software Carpentry notes on testing:
http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/advanced-swc/#testing-your-software

It talks basics about testing, including ideas of how to test your code (and retrofitting tests onto existing code). Seems up your alley.